# BibTeX Chapter Number not shown correctly

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, chapters

My BibLaTeX bibliography will not correctly display the chapter number for my bibliography, two problems occur, first the chapter number does not show in the table of contents like all other chapters and i would like this to be the case, secondly the chapter number shown is the chapter title is one less than it should be, for example chapter 6 is "6. conclusions" and the bibilography is displayed as "6. Works Cited", my apologies if this is dumb I am approx two days into LaTeX, my code is posted below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\author{Bob}
\title{Hey}
\date{Monday 1\textsuperscript{st} January 2018}

\hyphenpenalty=100000



\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle

\onehalfspacing

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents 
\newpage

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large\arabic{chapter}. }

%abstract goes here

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapInt}

\chapter{Aims and Objectives}\label{chapAim}

\chapter{Meathodology}\label{chapMeath}

\chapter{Results}\label{chapRes}

\chapter{Discussion}\label{chapDis}

\chapter{Conclusion}\label{chapCon}


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Works Cited}]
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `heading=bibnumbered`, instead of `heading=bibintoc`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newcommand{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\textrm{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\author{Bob}
\title{Hey}
\date{Monday 1\textsuperscript{st} January 2018}

\hyphenpenalty=100000



\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle

\onehalfspacing

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents 
\newpage

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large\arabic{chapter}. }

%abstract goes here

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapInt}

\chapter{Aims and Objectives}\label{chapAim}

\chapter{Meathodology}\label{chapMeath}

\chapter{Results}\label{chapRes}

\chapter{Discussion}\label{chapDis}

\chapter{Conclusion}\label{chapCon}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, title={Works Cited}]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]